# Using multiple mobile templates for different devices

Tags: magento

I'm currently using a [MobileDetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) class within a module for certain things (such as adding a "mobile" class to the body for styling etc). I've also been trying to think of ways of loading different templates for mobile, for example for the list view or the product page, **via xml**.

One way I was thinking this could be done is using a helper to set the template. So for example for the list view:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template helper="mobiledetect/switchTemplate" />                  
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

...then in my helper have:

```
public function switchTemplate()
{
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if($detect->isMobile()){ 
        $template = 'catalog/category/mobile_view.phtml'; 
    }
    else{ 
        $template = 'catalog/category/view.phtml'; 
    }; 
    return $template;
}
```

This works fine, but if I wanted to do something similar for other sections, for example the product detail page, I'd need to explicitly state each and every template in the helper.

Can anyone think of any way that it could be used to maybe just prefix the default template or something? So for example with the list view, the default is **catalog/category/view.phtml** - so if viewing on a mobile you'd get *mobile_* prepended to the standard template, thus getting **catalog/category/mobile_view.phtml**?

Or any other ideas on getting something similar accomplished? I'd like to be able to set things up from the local.xml, and not have to edit the helper every time I want to add a new mobile template.

I also thought about an observer to add a "mobile" handle for using in the xml layouts, but not 100% if that would work.

P.S. I know I could use a helper inside the template files to serve up different content for mobiles (I already do that) but I'm interested in the possibilities of doing this via a local.xml.

P.S.2 also, just to note, the reason I'm not wanting to use the standard design exceptions is I might want to have desktop/tablet/mobile versions of files for example.

Thanks in advance!

ANSWER: Based on Simon's answer I did the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/22579344/161056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about the magento default design exceptions? They allow to use a completly separted package or theme. By default the theme is chosen based on user agents. You could extend this with mobile detect. The theme is determined here: `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getTheme`

```
   // set exception value for theme, if defined in config
    $customThemeType = $this->_checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps("design/theme/{$type}_ua_regexp");
    if ($customThemeType) {
        $this->_theme[$type] = $customThemeType;
    }
```

This would be a good point to start.

Comment: Good thinking. If I can set up a custom hierarchy by extending that, then I wouldn't even need to use xml, I could just place any "mobile" files in the corresponding package to automatically override the base "desktop" version. Will definitely look into this, but am also still interested in any other ideas. Also, just to note, the reason I'm not wanting to use the standard design exceptions is I might want to have desktop/tablet/mobile versions of files for example.

Answer (score 1):

So, taking Simon's suggestion on board, I extended **Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package** and used the following:

```
const MOBILE_THEME = 'mobile';
const TABLET_THEME = 'tablet';

public function getTheme($type)
{

    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if($detect->isTablet()){ 
        $this->_theme[$type] = self::TABLET_THEME;
    }
    elseif($detect->isMobile()){ 
        $this->_theme[$type] = self::MOBILE_THEME;
    };           

    return $this->_theme[$type];

}
```

So basically, if a mobile or tablet is detected, it's essentially updating *System->Configuration->Design->Theme->Themes->Default* with either "mobile" or "tablet". This means I can then have the following theme structure:

```
app
- design
  - frontend
    - default
      - default
      - mobile
      - tablet
```

...and simply placing the template overrides in those folders will mean they get served up to the correct devices.

Seems to be working ok - if I run into any problems I'll post back.

Comment: is it good to go ? Did you have any problem with this ? I wonder if we can create a theme to make a magento website look more like a mobile app.

Comment: I haven't really used this in quite a while now, but it was working fine, and I never came across any issues with it.